# What is the easiest way to read/manipulate query string params using javascript?

Tags: javascript, query-string

The examples I've seen online seem much more complex than I expected *(manually parsing &/?/= into pairs, using regular expressions, etc).*  We're using asp.net ajax *(don't see anything in their client side reference)* and would consider adding jQuery if it would really help.

I would think there is a more elegant solution out there - so far [this is the best code I've found](http://www.bloggingdeveloper.com/post/JavaScript-QueryString-ParseGet-QueryString-with-Client-Side-JavaScript.aspx) but I would love to find something more along the lines of the HttpRequest.QueryString object *(asp.net server side)*.  Thanks in advance,

Shane

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change URL parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090948/change-url-parameters)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is indeed a [QueryString plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/query-object) for jQuery, if you're willing to install the jQuery core and the plugin it could prove useful.

Comment: After a bit of work we're slowly porting our asp.net apps to jquery.  The library has really impressed us and soon to be distributed by Microsoft so if you are facing similar JS issues/questions I recommend checking out jQuery

Comment: Over a year later - we've jumped into jquery with both feet and we highly recommend it for parsing the querystring or just about any client side task

Answer (score 10):

I am using this function in case i don't want to use a plugin:

```
function getQueryVariable(variable) {
    var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var vars = query.split("&");
    for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
        var pair = vars[i].split("=");
        if (pair[0] == variable) {
            return pair[1];
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at my post, as it tells you exactly how to do this:

http://seattlesoftware.wordpress.com/2008/01/16/javascript-query-string/

Comment: +1 because it doesn't use any 3rd party librariers, sometimes you just can't import them (e.g. when working on a widget/gadget).

Answer (score 2):

For jQuery I suggest [jQuery BBQ: Back Button & Query Library](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/) By "Cowboy" Ben Alman

> jQuery BBQ leverages the HTML5
>   hashchange event to allow simple, yet
>   powerful bookmarkable #hash history.
>   In addition, jQuery BBQ provides a
>   full .deparam() method, along with
>   both hash state management, and
>   fragment / query string parse and
>   merge utility methods.

Example:

```
// Parse URL, deserializing query string into an object.
// http://www.example.com/foo.php?a=1&b=2&c=hello#test
// search is set to ?a=1&b=2&c=hello
// myObj is set to { a:"1", b:"2", c:"hello" }
var search = window.location.search;
var myObj = $.deparam.querystring( search );
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the String utility from prototypejs.org, called toQueryParams().

Example from their site: http://prototypejs.org/api/string/toQueryParams

> 'section=blog&id=45'.toQueryParams();
>   // -> {section: 'blog', id: '45'}
>
> 'section=blog;id=45'.toQueryParams();
>   // -> {section: 'blog', id: '45'}
>
> 'http://www.example.com?section=blog&id=45#comments'.toQueryParams();
>   // -> {section: 'blog', id: '45'}
>
> 'section=blog&tag=javascript&tag=prototype&tag=doc'.toQueryParams();
>   // -> {section: 'blog', tag: ['javascript', 'prototype', 'doc']}
>
> 'tag=ruby%20on%20rails'.toQueryParams();
>   // -> {tag: 'ruby on rails'}
>
> 'id=45&raw'.toQueryParams();
>   // -> {id: '45', raw: undefined}

Also, you may use the alias parseQuery() to obtain the same results.

```
window.location.search.parseQuery();
```

Since window.location returns an object, you must obtain the string.

Answer (score 1):

```
  *$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#a").click(function () {
                window.location.href = "secondpage.aspx?id='0' & name='sunil'& add='asr' & phone='1234'";
            });
        });*


**then read the query string parameters on another using split method . Here as follows:**


  *$(document).ready(function () {
            var a = decodeURI(window.location.search);
            var id = window.location.search = "id=" + $().val();
            var name = a.split("name=")[1].split("&")[0].split("'")[1];
            var phone = a.split("phone=")[1].split("&")[0].split("'")[1];
            var add = a.split("add=")[1].split("&")[0].split("'")[1];
            alert(id+','+name+','+add+','+phone); 
        });*
```

Answer (score 1):

If there's any possibility of encountering repeated parameters (e.g. ?tag=foo&tag=bar), most libraries out there won't be sufficient. In that case, you might want to consider this library that I developed from Jan Wolter's [very comprehensive parser](http://unixpapa.com/js/querystring.html). I added .plus() and .minus() functions and roundtripping:

https://github.com/timmc/js-tools/blob/master/src/QueryString.js