# How do I grab variables from a url with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

basically I have a link like so:

```
<a href="file.php?value=this&something=so&please=help">special link</a>
```

And when I click it, I want to be able to easily refer to the variables.

So for example something like

```
$(document).ready(function){

    $('a').click(function(){

        var myvalue = $(this).attr('href........

        /// and thats as far as I know!

        return false;

    });

});
```

How do I access those variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing built-in jQuery that will allow you to do this. You could use a [plugin](http://projects.allmarkedup.com/jquery_url_parser/) to parse urls. So basically your code could look like:

```
$('a').click(function(evt) {
    var myValue = jQuery.url.setUrl(this.href).param('value');
    evt.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

jQuery doesn't have support for reading a query string built in (or if it does, I never found it).

You could manually process document.location.search, but then you'd have to manually split it on & (and then again on =) as well as url decode it.

However, there are some jQuery plugins to do this for you:

- [Query String Object](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/query-object)
- [URL Utils](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ba-jquery-url-utils-plugin)

Strangely, jQuery has a built-in function to do the opposite... [$.param(obj)](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.param#obj) will turn an array or javascript object into a query string for you.

Answer (score 1):

[location.search](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/javascript/11197.asp) is what I would use, not sure why you need jquery.  Also if you're dealing with links, try using [link.search](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/javascript/11185.asp)

this quick snippet works

```
<a href='http://www.google.com/?id=asdfasdfasdf' id='tes1'>asdfasdf</a>
<input type='button' onclick='alert(document.getElementById("tes1").search)'>
```

Answer (score 1):

To merely grab them you'd need something like this:

```
var urlstring = window.location.search;
```

To manipulate them, there are already answers on SO, for instance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090948/change-url-parameters-with-jquery/1091083#1091083).

Answer (score 1):

And if you want a really nice function to take a URL and give you all the parts, I recommend the ever popular [PHP.JS](http://phpjs.org) function [parse_url](http://phpjs.org/functions/parse_url:485)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a simple function as suggested above - split on the ampersand and again on the equal sign.

```
var urlObj = location.search
var params = urlObj.slice(1).split("&")
var map = {}
for (var i=0; i < params.length; i++){
     var item = params[i]
     var key = item.match(/^.*\=/)[0].replace(/\=/,"")
     var value = item.match(/\=.*$/)[0].replace(/\=/,"")
     map[key] = value
}
```