# How to add/change param value to url using jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, url

I am trying to add two parameters to the url (in the address bar).

Basically a user click this link from a different location `<a href="player.php">open player</a>`

I need to automatically load the the latest show from that list of shows displayed, the show is shown every day so i do not know the episode number.

the address bar needs to be like this when I load the page `http://localhost/player.php?v=11145&a=true`

I have this

```
var autoplay = "$('.link:first').attr('href');
var loadUrl = "http://localhost/player.php";
or 
var loadUrl = window.location.href;
```

but not sure how to load and attach the params. Any suggestions of any good techns to do this would be good

Comment: duplicate - u can see a lot of answers in the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090948/change-url-parameters-with-jquery

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change URL parameters and specify defaults using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090948/change-url-parameters-and-specify-defaults-using-javascript)