# How to refresh a page with jQuery by passing a parameter to URL

Tags: jquery, url, parameter-passing

I am refreshing my page using jQuery:

```
location.reload();
```

This is working great but I want to refresh the same page by passing a parameter to URL.

How can I do this by using jQuery?

Ex:

If my url is `www.myweb.com`, I want to refresh this by passing a parameter like this

```
  www.myweb.com?single
```

Thank you

Comment: updated my answer to check for already altered URL

Comment: If this is literally what you want, most of the answers here will work. But if what you actually want is to reload the page with altered request parameters, refer to my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33361578/1450294

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this by using location.href

```
if(window.location.hostname == "www.myweb.com")
   window.location.href += "?single";
```

Comment: Thank You this is working great. But i am getting problem from the next refresh.

Comment: First time url is : www.myweb.com/?single
second time url is : www.myweb.com/?single?single How can i avoid repeated parameters ?

Comment: `if(window.location.hostname == "www.myweb.com" && window.location.search != '?single')` ?

Comment: instead of using `.hostname` you could try to use `href` as it will be the full url. other options on the location object are found here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location

Comment: @KillerFish: A less hackish solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33361578/1450294

Answer (score 57):

I would use [REGEX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) with `.replace` like this:

```
window.location.href = window.location.href.replace( /[\?#].*|$/, "?single" );
```

Comment: This method is very good because it does not append a parameter to an existing parameters!

Comment: @BennyNeugebauer: Sometimes, though, you'll want to keep the existing parameters. For those cases, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33361578/1450294

Comment: Elegant solution! I've searched far and wide to find this.

Answer (score 28):

You can use Javascript [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/set).

```
var url = new URL(window.location.href);
url.searchParams.set('single','');
window.location.href = url.href;
```

[UPDATE]: If IE support is a need, check this thread:

[SCRIPT5009: 'URLSearchParams' is undefined in IE 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45758837/script5009-urlsearchparams-is-undefined-in-ie-11)

Thanks @john-m to talk about the IE support

Comment: If IE support is a need, check this thread:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45758837/script5009-urlsearchparams-is-undefined-in-ie-11

Answer (score 3):

Concision counts: I prefer `window.location = "?single";` or `window.location += "?single";`

Answer (score 3):

You could simply have just done:

```
var varAppend = "?single";
window.location.href = window.location.href.replace(".com",".com" + varAppend);
```

Unlike the other answers provided, there is no needless conditional check. If you design your project properly, you'll let the interface make the decision making and calling that statement whenever an event has been triggered.

Since there will only be one ".com" in your url, it will just replace `.com` with `.com?single`. I just added `varAppend` just in case you want to make it easier to modify the code in the future with different kinds of url variables.

One other note:
The `.replace` works by adding to the href since href returns a string containing the full url address information.

Answer (score 3):

if `window.location.hash` is empty, you cant assign to location.href a new value without using a correct function (at least tested in chrome).

try the `window.location.replace`:

```
if (!window.location.hash) 
    {
        window.location.replace(window.location.href + "?single")
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Click these links to see these more flexible and robust solutions. They're answers to a similar question:

- With jQuery and the *query* plug-in: [`window.location.search = jQuery.query.set('single', true);`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1090966/1450294)
- Without jQuery: [Use `parse` and `stringify` on `window.location.search`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19965480/1450294)

These allow you to programmatically set the parameter, and, unlike the other hacks suggested for this question, won't break for URLs that already have a parameter, or if something else isn't quite what you thought might happen.

Answer (score 1):

```
var singleText = "single";
var s = window.location.search;

if (s.indexOf(singleText) == -1) {
    window.location.href += (s.substring(0,1) == "?") ? "&" : "?" + singleText;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Jquery Load to handels this, works great for me.
check out my code from my project. I need to refresh with arguments to put Javascript variable into php

```
if (isset($_GET['language'])){
    $language = $_GET['language'];
}else{
    echo '<script>';    
    echo '  var userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;';
    echo '  if(userLang.search("zh") != -1) {';
    echo '      var language = "chn";';
    echo '  }else{';
    echo '      var language = "eng";';
    echo '  }';
    echo '$("html").load("index.php","language=" + language);';
    echo '</script>';
    die;
}
```

Comment: Or just add the url into the dom and then use jquery to pull it from the parameter. No need for an entire javascript code

Answer (score 0):

I used this exact thing before, I have a custom function that I used for the if statement like mentioned by Mark Coleman aswell as submitted a shorter version of his answer but just for the kicks, here is my version

```
function isOfType(sParam) {
   var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
   var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
   var sParameterName = sURLVariables[0];
   return (sParameterName.toLowerCase() == sParam)
}
```

once you have that function you will use it like this

```
if(!isOfType('single'))
    window.location.href += '?single';
```

Comment: In 2021 there's not much point to this answer. Every modern browser now supports URLSearchParam.has() --> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/has