# Reload a page from another page

Tags: jquery

I want to reload another page during success in Ajax

```
success: function(data) {
      var partA = '/partA-revenue-yesterday';
      var location = partA;
      console.log(data);
      location.reload(partA);
    },
```

where var partA is a route on the same website

Comment: if that is a route then just navigate to it, you can reload it before load.

Comment: How is the other page connected to the parent page?

Comment: the submit form where ajax resides is in different page, and the page where I intended to refresh is in the different page

Answer (score 0):

The **Location.reload()** method reloads the resource from the current URL.parameters it accepts is *true* or *false* , if its *true* then page current reloads with hard refresh and no cache

Use **Location.replace()** method , which replaces the current resource with the one at the provided URL.

Want to know how to manipulate the URL .[***Click here***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233050/how-to-refresh-a-page-with-jquery-by-passing-a-parameter-to-url)