# SCRIPT5009: 'URLSearchParams' is undefined in IE 11

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to execute the [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) but I get an error on IE 11 since it is not supported there. It's working perfectly in Chrome and Firefox.

How can I get the equivalent functionality in IE 11?
I am executing the code in Laravel 5.4.

Here is the line of code which I'm trying to execute.

```
var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
```

Error:

> SCRIPT5009: 'URLSearchParams' is undefined

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Got a solution by replacing the code with the following:

```
$.urlParam = function(name){
    var results = new RegExp('[\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
    if (results == null){
       return null;
    }
    else {
       return decodeURI(results[1]) || 0;
    }
}
```

So for example "example.com?param1=name&param2=&id=6"

```
$.urlParam('param1');  // name
$.urlParam('id');      // 6
$.urlParam('param2');  // null
```

Comment: Hi there
I don't understand how you have managed to assign the value 'name' to the parameter 'param1', same for all the others parameter. 
Can you please explain that?
In my case I have:
`var parameters = new URLSearchParams();

and a function setProfile(value){
 parameters.append("ProfileId", value);
}`


Thanks

Comment: I don't really understand how people are able to find solutions in Regex. Thanks a lot! Saved my time.

Answer (score 40):

Odhikari's answer as a (partial) polyfill:

```
(function (w) {

    w.URLSearchParams = w.URLSearchParams || function (searchString) {
        var self = this;
        self.searchString = searchString;
        self.get = function (name) {
            var results = new RegExp('[\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(self.searchString);
            if (results == null) {
                return null;
            }
            else {
                return decodeURI(results[1]) || 0;
            }
        };
    }

})(window)
```

Comment: Good because does not create a new function but implements missing one, so copy-paste should work for everyone.

Comment: Using `decodeURIComponent` instead of `decodeURI` is a more complete solution, I'd say.

Comment: I like this approach however if you need to use append (i.e. `URLSearchParams.append()` it doesn't work.

Comment: Hence 'partial'.

Comment: You can add support for the `has()` method to @AndyTaw's answer by adding this under the self.get definition: 
`self.has = function (name) { var results = new RegExp('[\?&]' + name).exec(self.searchString); if (results == null) { return null; } else { return true; }}` and you can add support for other methods (like `append()` as needed in a similar manner.

Answer (score 20):

If anyone finds this in 2019, corejs now also supports URLSearchParams as a polyfill, so you can just stay with corejs and don't have to brew together something yourselves.

```
import 'core-js/features/url-search-params';
```

https://github.com/zloirock/core-js#url-and-urlsearchparams

Comment: Works for Angular. Thanks

Comment: Works with JQuery. Toodle pip!

Comment: What version of core-js does this require?

Answer (score 10):

I was able to solve this by using [url-search-params-polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/url-search-params-polyfill). Just import into the file you're using URLSearchParams in:

```
import 'url-search-params-polyfill';
```

And your existing references to URLSearchParams should now work!

Comment: another way to import:   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/url-search-params/1.1.0/url-search-params.js"></script>

Answer (score 2):

I have had a similar issue when trying to use **URLSearchParams** when trying to make an **AXIOS** Post when using Internet Explorer.  So its a little different from your description, but I'd like to post my resolution here just in case.

Here's my **AXIOS** post code from my React app that works just fine for Edge, Chrome and Firefox, but on IE it gives me the error

> SCRIPT5009: URLSearchParams is undefined

:

```
        let axiosConfig = {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }
        };            
        // Putting together the data to be passed to local servlet.
        const params = new URLSearchParams();
        params.append('var1', this.state.data1);
        params.append('var2', this.state.data2);

        var urlToPost = 'https://localhost:8080/someLocalServlet/doSomething';

        var self = this;  
        axios.post(urlToPost, params, axiosConfig)
            .then((res) => {
                // Handling Response from Servlet.
                console.log("AXIOS POST RESPONSE RECEIVED: ", res);

            })
            .catch((err) => {
                // Handler exception error thrown by Servlet.
                console.log("AXIOS POST ERROR: ", err);

            })
```

To get it to work with IE I used **jQuery** to do the Post and used a **var** object instead of **URLSearchParams**.
The if statement below checks to see if the user is on IE :

```
    if((navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") !== -1 ) || (!!document.documentMode === true )) { //IF IE > 10
        var myObject = {
            var1: this.state.data1,
            var2: this.state.data2
        };
        var urlToPostTo = 'https://localhost:8080/someLocalServlet/doSomething';

        $.post(urlToPost, myObject, 
            function(result) {  
                alert( "success" );
            })
              .done(function(result) {
                alert( "second success" );
              })
              .fail(function(result) {
                alert( "error" );
              })
              .always(function(result) {
                    alert( "finished" );
              });        
    } else {
       // use the AXIOS POST code above
    }
```

To get the jQuery, I did have to do

> npm install jquery

Then on top of my React file I imported the following:

```
import $ from 'jquery'; 
import { polyfill } from 'es6-promise'; polyfill();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class UrlSearchParams {
  constructor(query) {
    this.query = query;
  }
  getSearchObject = () => {
    const { query } = this;
    return query
    ? (/^[?#]/.test(query) ? query.slice(1) : query)
      .split("&")
      .reduce((params, param) => {
        let [key, value] = param.split("=");
        params[key] = value
          ? decodeURIComponent(value.replace(/\+/g, " "))
          : "";
        return params;
      }, {})
  : {};
  };
  getAll = () => {
    const searchParams = this.getSearchObject();
    return searchParams;
  }
  get = param => {
    const searchParams = this.getSearchObject();
    return searchParams[param];
  };
  setUrl = (param, value) => {
    const searchParams = this.getSearchObject();
    searchParams[param] = value;
    return Object.keys(searchParams)
    .map(key => key + "=" + searchParams[key])
    .join("&");
  };
}

export default UrlSearchParams;
```

Comment: This will not work on IE, how the question specifically asks for. No version of IE supports Class or Arrow function. Not to speak of the 'export default'. It's good code otherwise,except for a missing encodeURIComponent on setURL.