# How to create a url string with query parameters from an object in Angular 5+?

Tags: angular, url, angular5

I am trying to create a URL from an object in an Angular 5 SPA. My code looks like the following:

```
import { UrlTree, UrlSegmentGroup, DefaultUrlSerializer, UrlSegment } from "@angular/router";

const urlTree = new UrlTree();
urlTree.root = new UrlSegmentGroup([new UrlSegment("EndPoint", {})], {});
urlTree.queryParams = {
  "param1": param1Value,
  "param2": param2Value
};
const urlSerializer = new DefaultUrlSerializer();
const url = urlSerializer.serialize(urlTree);
```

It does the job, but it seems to include significant overhead for such a trivial job and I am wondering if there is a more straightforward method to obtain the url from the object.

My expectation is to have something simple as:

```
const url = someSerializer.serialize("/segment1/segment2", { 
  "param1": param1Value,
  "param2": param2Value
})
```

**Question:** How to create a url string with query parameters from an object in Angular 5+?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you already have `queryParams: Params`, either from building the object yourself or getting it from the current `route`, you can simply use:

```
const queryParamsString = new HttpParams({ fromObject: queryParams }).toString();
```

`queryParamsString` will be `param1=somevalue1&param2=somevalue2&...`

Don't forget to prepend the `?` to it if you're appending this to some URL.

Comment: As long as we don't need to merge the query params (like with `queryParamsHandling`) this answer works well.

Answer (score 49):

You can use just `Router` and `UrlSerializer`:

```
constructor(private router: Router, private serializer: UrlSerializer) {
  const tree = router.createUrlTree([], { queryParams: { foo: 'a', bar: 42 } });
  console.log(serializer.serialize(tree)); // "/?foo=a&bar=42"
}
```

See demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-basic-template-3hx9at?file=src/app/hello.component.ts

Comment: this would work but is it not the good practice to use the constructor only for dependency injection and use `ngOnInit` for all the other work?

Comment: It works, but I have to strip the segments that are automatically put based on current component route.

Comment: Is there an inverse operation too?

Comment: In Angular 8, it outputs now matrix notation: ;foo=a;bar=42

Comment: you don't need the router or the serializer (which by the way is also in the router, so you don't need to inject the serializer separatly)

Comment: @martin Like @Andre said, you don't need the serializer because the router has a method called `serializeUrl` that can be used.

Comment: @StefanFalk The inverse can be done by calling `UrlSerializer.parse('/segment1/segment2?foo=a&bar=42')`, which returns a `UrlTree` with the query params intact.

Answer (score 33):

You can directly use it in queryParams if you ultimately want to navigate through Angular's routing module.

```js
let params = {
    param1: param1Value,
    param2: param2Value
};
    
this.router.navigate('/segment1/segment2', { queryParams: params });
```

For static URLs:

```js
const params = new HttpParams()
   .set('param1', param1Value)
   .set('param2', param2Value);

const URL = 'yourEndPoint/segment1/segment2?' + params.toString();
```

For more details and examples see:
https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/angular-pass-url-parameters-query-strings/

Comment: For navigation it is fine, but I want to construct a URL to fetch some data from an API.

Comment: the second method in this answers allow you to create a URL string that you can use anywhere, including API calls

Answer (score 9):

In case you want to build an utility to construct a query string from an object, try Angular `HttpParams`:

```js
// initialize from an object
const obj: any = {
  'number': 123,
  'string': 'lincoln',
  'empty': null,
  'bool': true,
  'array': ['1991', null, 'ramanujan'],
}
let httpParams = new HttpParams({ fromObject: obj })

// append manually
// do not forget to reassign
httpParams = httpParams.append('extra', 'gimme a chance')

console.log(httpParams.toString())

// number=123&string=lincoln&empty=null&bool=true&array=1991&array=null&array=ramanujan&extra=gimme%20a%20chance
```

Note that `HttpParams` only accepts `key` in `string` and `value` in `string | string[]`. Therefore, marking `obj` as `any` makes `obj` valid in code editor. Another note is that `HttpParams` splits every item in an array into **separate parameters with the same name**, which might not what you expected.

If you prefer something more "native", [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) is a candidate. This one supports pretty much the same methods in `HttpParams` like `append`, `delete`, `has` etc. Syntaxes are slightly less verbose. Every value in object will force `toString`, so an array results in one parameter only, as opposed to the behavior in `HttpParams`.

```js
const obj: any = {
  number: 123,
  arr: [999, 'michael'],
  str: 'simp',
  empty1: null,
  empty2: undefined,
  canSleep: false,
}

const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(obj)

// no need to reassign after appending
searchParams.append('more', 'gimme one more kiss')

console.log(searchParams.toString())
// number=123&arr=999%2Cmichael&str=simp&empty1=null&empty2=undefined&canSleep=false&more=gimme+one+more+kiss
```

`URLSearchParams` is supported in most modern browsers, Node.js and Web Workers. To use it in IE, please [provide a polyfill](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56238787/6755585).

Answer (score 7):

You can take the same approach as the Angular HttpClient

```js
const url = 'https://example.com'

const params = new HttpParams()
  .set('key1', 'Value 1')
  .set('key2', 'Value 2')

const request = new HttpRequest('GET', url, null, {params});

request.urlWithParams
```

The advantage of this approach is that the HttpParams class handles URL encoding of the parameters and the HttpRequest handles cases when the URL has existing params or simply has a '?' at the end.

Answer (score 5):

Try like this:

```
  let httpParams = new HttpParams().set('params1', String(id));
  httpParams = httpParams.set('params2', String(name));

  return this.httpClient.get<any>(this.BASE_URL, {
          params: httpParams
        });
```

Answer (score -4):

You can construct a url while making a call to api to fetch data like this:

```
GetData(id) {

    this.http.get<User>('http://test.com' + id + '/users')
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data)
      });
}
```

Comment: I tried this way but if you have special chars inside your query, like quotes, this doesn't work even with escaped quotes.