# What's the best way to return a clean URL by removing unwanted query params while keeping others?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to have redirect rules for this page's routes that has unwanted query params. So this is what it looks like with the default unwanted query params.

`https://some-test-url.com/b/laptops/1117?clubId=6612&offset=0&rootDimension=pcs_availability%253AOnlinepipsymbBrand%253ADell&searchCategoryId=1117&selectedFilter=all&sortKey=relevance&sortOrder=1`

It should redirect to the cleaned URL. It should clean these from the URL under these conditions which are the default values. For the `limit` it should be removing both 48 and 20. I'm assuming that any other query params should be left that aren't listed below since they're not defaults.

```
searchCategoryId=all
selectedFilter=all
sortKey=relevance&sortOrder=1
limit=48 on desktop or limit=20 on mweb
clubId ever
offset=0
```

So the cleaned URL from above should look something like this

`https://some-test-url.com/b/laptops/1117?rootDimension=pcs_availability%253AOnlinepipsymbBrand%253ADell`

But for example if it's not a default query params for example

`www.test.com/blah?offset=40&selectedFilter=online&clubId=3422`

it should return

`www.test.com/blah?offset=40&selectedFilter=online`

What would be the best way to handle this? I tried doing it with regex but I wasn't able to get the expected result since it's a bit more complicated. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `URLSearchParams` which is supported on all major browsers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams

Something like:

```js
const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.href);
for (var key of params.keys()){
    // do something with logic from your allow/block list
    // such as removing it:
    params.delete(key);
}
```

Comment: This is almost always the right solution.  However, if you're modifying a URL for a service out of your control, there are edge cases that can get more complicated.  Sometimes, specific order or existence of the parameters matters.  For example, I can't share my state government's website URLs on Facebook because they add their `fbclid` parameter, removing empty query string parameters in the process.  One of those parameters has to exist, even if it has no value.  These are rare cases but I've seen a handful of sites like this.

Comment: Thank you! This definitely looks like what I'm looking for! I'll implement this and see how it goes!

Comment: Actually it looks like it's not supported by the worst browser IE. Unfortunately it has to be supported by IE for it to be viable.

Comment: Yeah when I said major browser I did not intend to include IE, I consider IE to be a deprecated browser at this point. You can still make this work with poly fill: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56238787/3267920