# passing parameters in url to another page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am going to create two pages.

The first page will be www.rentzamm.com?adv=1256&loc=768 ...On this page I am going to have a link which takes you to www.rentzamm.com/result.asp ..... Now when i press the link from page 1 I want the link of page 2 to be like this: www.rentzamm.com/result.asp?adv=1256&loc=768 ... is this possible please?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090948/change-url-parameters-with-jquery

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use hidden variables.

and construct the url for the onclick event of anchor tag.
But please dont pass sensitive information like this since the request can be modified..

Pkv

Comment: sorry did not understand your post.... the links i posted are just an example....

Comment: Seems you didn't even read the title of the question? It clearly says 'passing parameters in url'.

Comment: any help on my request please? the possible duplicate post is not the same issue that i have :/