# get/change/remove URL parameters with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

I was looking over [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090948/change-url-parameters-with-jquery) and searching google but I didn't find any update, so I am wondering if any of you know anything more recent because the last update on

https://github.com/blairmitchelmore/jquery.plugins was in 2009 and 2010 on https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-bbq

Or any other ideas? I need to add/change/remove parameters to my url

Comment: You'd like to alter the URL after having a loaded page?

Comment: yes... exactly, after the page has been loaded

Comment: This is tough to do, mainly because of the security issues involved. Are you unable to use either of the plugins you linked to? I'd imagine these would only manipulate the hash value.

Comment: i didn't tried them out because I am looking first for a more recent version to see if something... if not than I will see if they work. From 2009 to 2012 something better could've appeared

Comment: Manipulating query parameters is such a basic thing that it doesn't hardly matter whether the code is brand new or several years old.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Its easy to do by pure JS.

See this code from [www.samaxes.com](http://www.samaxes.com/2011/09/change-url-parameters-with-jquery/)

```
var queryParameters = {}, queryString = location.search.substring(1),
    re = /([^&=]+)=([^&]*)/g, m;

while (m = re.exec(queryString)) {
    queryParameters[decodeURIComponent(m[1])] = decodeURIComponent(m[2]);
}

// Add new parameters or update existing ones
queryParameters['newParameter'] = 'new parameter';
queryParameters['existingParameter'] = 'new value';
location.search = $.param(queryParameters);
```

Its not flawless. But at least it can give you some idea.

**Update 1:**
[Here](http://shiplu.mokadd.im/61/parse-query-string-by-pure-javascrirpt/) is a function I wrote for another answer (cant remember). It works perfect.

Comment: Wouldn't location.search reload the page? I suppose this is Ok if that works for the op. I figured that a reload was undesirable.

Comment: No. `location.search` contains the query string with `?` added. Its a string.

Comment: Typing location.search = "foobar" into the console causes a page reload.

Comment: @hackNightly Yes. it'll reload the page. In fact OP want to change the param of query string so that it reloads.

Comment: Oh, ok, that makes more sense. Good call.

Comment: yes, but this is used only to set... not to get the value of an existing one... right?

Comment: @w0rldart If value can not be get how can it be set? `queryParameters['existingParameter']` gets value of parameter `existingParameter`.