# Reload the same page when click

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to Reload the same page when I click on reload button.any one give the C# code for achieve this?

Comment: What are you using? ASP.NET?

Comment: @harry180 it is not working ....

Comment: I've make mistake in my 1-st comment for what I'm truly sorry correct syntax is: `Response.Redirect(Page.Request.RawUrl,false);`

Answer (score 16):

You can use

```
Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
```

Which I found by googling your title.

You can look there for more informations :

- [How to reload the same page on a button click , with the data from database and ignoring the changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9078728/how-to-reload-the-same-page-on-a-button-click-with-the-data-from-database-and#)
- [How do I refresh the page in ASP.NET? (Let it reload itself by code)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206507/how-to-refresh-the-page-in-asp-net-let-it-reload-itself-by-code#)
- http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?316778-How-to-programmatically-refresh-a-page-in-asp.net

Answer (score 6):

You can use like this

```
Page.Redirect(Page.Request.RawUrl,false);
```

Or suppose you are on `default.aspx` and you want get back on the same page use

```
Page.Redirect("default.aspx",false);
```