# Javascript / jQuery get all url parameters and add/change one

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, parameters

I have the following url

```
http://www.domain.com?page=options&tab=general
```

I want to be able to get to the tab parameter and change it e.g

I have two tabs General & Styles and when I click on styles, I want a hidden field(that has this url as a value) to change so that it reads the same url but with the tabs parameter changed to styles. So it would look like this

```
http://www.domain.com?page=options&tab=styles
```

However, this url may not have the parameter tab when the page is loaded so i need to be able to add a parameter to the url query string.

There will be many more tabs so I cannot just replace the text general with styles

Anyone know? 
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change URL parameters with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090948/change-url-parameters-with-jquery)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var s = "http://www.domain.com?page=options&tab=general"
var queryString = s.substring(s.lastIndexOf("?") + 1);
var newQueryString = $.map(queryString.split("&"), function(pair) { 
  var p = pair.split("="); 
  if (p[1] == "general") { 
    p[1] = "styles";
    return p.join("=");
  } else { 
    return pair;
  } 
}).join("&");
```

Comment: Great solution! As a note: if you don't want to use a hardcoded url, you can retrieve it with jquery: var url = window.location.href;