# Javascript to pass var onclick select and checkbox

Tags: javascript, checkbox

So my page has two columns. On the right column the results are displayed.

The results include all the elements. On the right column i have a  and few check boxes. I am able to populate the checkboxes depending on the option selected in .

I have to click submit to get the data on the right column. I don't want AJAX. I want the page to be refreshed with the option in  selected and the results to be displayed based on that. I am able to code the php part. To GET the value of the option selected in

So my code is :

```
<select id="theselect" onclick = "afterChange()">
    <option value="0"> Select the Department </option>
    <option value="11"> Department11 </option>
    <option value="22"> Department22 </option>
    <option value="33"> Department33 </option>
</select>


var url = location.href;
document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML = url;

function afterChange(){
var dept = document.getElementById("theselect").value;
  if (dept && dept!= 0) {
  var myline = url + "&dept=" + dept;
  document.getElementById("mynewdiv").innerHTML = myline;
  window.location= myline;
  }
}

<p id='mydiv'> </p> <br />
<p id='mynewdiv'> </p>

<?php 
 if(isset($_GET['dept'])) {

 $cat = $_GET['dept'];

 echo "You are now searching in $cat";

 //code to show content from database for that department

?>
```

I know that there is a better way to do this which m unaware of. So far the code works fine for the first time. I am able to get the results from the DB according to the SELECT option.
But when i change the select, it takes the entire URL again and adds the new value of SELECT to the URL, that confuses PHP.

So if my site URL is : 
    http://mysite.php?dept=22
After changing SELECT 2nd time, it changes to 
    http://mysite.php?dept=22&dept=33

I also have few checkboxes after the SELECT.

I want the results to be sorted based on the select and the checkboxes.

I know there must be an easy way to do it, but i am struggling to find it.

Please help me in understanding this concept. Thank you so very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With

```
  var url = location.href;
```

You will always get the current url. Means on 2nd refresh the `url` will be `http://mysite.php?dept=22` now you add your dept again:

```
var myline = url + "&dept=" + dept;
```

Which produces the error you described.
To handle this problem you have to strip the old parameter first or if you only need one parameter do something like:

```
var url = location.origin + location.pathname
```

instead of `location.href` for more information you can read [this](http://de.selfhtml.org/javascript/objekte/location.htm?test)

Comment: How do i replace only a particular var from the URL? I may have the var for another Dept in the URL, so how do i replace only a particular var ? Thanks.

Comment: [This question will help you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13063838/add-change-parameter-of-url-and-redirect-to-the-new-url) ;)