# Adding GET parameter on url with a tag

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I have a url that looks like this

```
mysite.com/index.php?page=home&gender=female&age=22
```

or

```
mysite.com/index.php?page=home&gender=female&occupation=programmer
```

How can I append a new parram `orderby=value` and `order=asc` using `a` tag like how the submit button works.

like when I click the link Name It will add new param on the link a I can sort the data by it

```
<a href="#">Name</a> | <a href="#">Age</a>
```

like how wordpresshandles it

```
wordpress/wp-admin/users.php?orderby=login&order=desc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the function posted here https://stackoverflow.com/a/6021027/1021726. All credit goes to *amateur*.

The function either creates a new value on the query string or updates an existing value.

Add an onclick event on the `<a>` tag and call the function like

```
updateQueryStringParameter(window.url, "orderby", "myName");
updateQueryStringParameter(window.url, "order", "desc");
```

Comment: @Cindy93 - thats another solution to the problem and without knowing how your application looks like it's difficult for any of us to know what would be best.

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you just build the URLs during the template render? No need for JS

eg

```
<a href="/index.php?occupation=programmer&orderby=name&order=desc">Name</a>
```

Just check the current order value when you render and invert it.

Obviously if you're using AJAX this is less useful.

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
document.URL + "orderby=desc"
```

The only problem is that when you click again you get orderby twice. Therefore you should check if the url already contains the orderby parameter.

A more complex function to set or replace url parameters could be found here:

[Add / Change parameter of URL and redirect to the new URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13063838/add-change-parameter-of-url-and-redirect-to-the-new-url)

Comment: Yes, there will be a missing & or ? though

Answer (score 2):

use it

```
var url = document.URL;
if(url.indexOf('orderby') == -1){
url = document.URL + "orderby=desc";
}
```

Comment: Yes, there will be a missing & or ? though