# How to change I18N locale NOT by querystring?

Tags: java, javascript, struts2

This is a `struts2` question.

Currently, I am using i18n for internationalization in my webapp.
Some of my jsp pages has querystring to store the request information.
For example,

```
http://myWebsite.com/myWebsite/myPage?productId=12345
```

When users try to switch language, I rewrite the URL by `javascript` to

```
http://myWebsite.com/myWebsite/myPage?request_locale=zh_CN
```

**And it loses the query string.**

And my urls are used in different ways:

```
http://myWebsite.com/myWebsite/myPage
http://myWebsite.com/myWebsite/myPage?productId=12345#myAnchor
http://myWebsite.com/myWebsite/myPage?productId=12345&key2=value2&key3=value3#myAnchor
http://myWebsite.com/myWebsite/myPage?productId=12345&key2=value2&key3=value3&request_locale=zh_CN
http://myWebsite.com/myWebsite/myPage?productId=12345&key2=value2&key3=value3
...
```

When I try to handle all this differences in `javascript`, it becomes so complicated.

Is there any good way to retain the querystrings and anchors after switching locale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you rewrite the URL using JS, you should do it based on the current URL.

So, if in the browser is showed

```
http://myWebsite.com/myWebsite/myPage?productId=12345
```

you should rewrite it as

```
http://myWebsite.com/myWebsite/myPage?productId=12345&request_locale=zh_CN
```

For that, using JS you should get the current URL displayed. Take a look to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1034621/980472) for how to.

Comment: I am actually doing this in javascript. When the request_locale is part of the url and it's in the middle of the querystring. It becomes very hard to handle. (becasue user may switch language mutliple times)

Comment: So, you should analyse the URL, remove language parameter and add the new one. It shouldn't be so hard. JQuery can help you to do that. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1090985/980472