# modernizr and ajax load conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, modernizr

I have a page using modernizr.js and a custom ajax function that reloads the page content every x seconds. Here's the code for the triggered functions.

```
function reloadSlides() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: document.location.href,
        cache: true,
        success: function(html){
            jQuery('#main').html(html);
        }
    });
}
```

When I look into the DOM inspector, the classes start to repeat again and again in the HTML tag, like this:

> html lang="de" class=" js no-touch cssanimations csstransitions js no-touch cssanimations csstransitions js no-touch cssanimations csstransitions js no-touch cssanimations csstransitions js no-touch cssanimations csstransitions js no-touch cssanimations csstransitions" style=""

why is that? and how can I avoid this?

Thanks for looking!

Comment: It looks like modernizr is being loaded every time you reload the page content. Try reloading *only* the content you want to refresh, rather than the entire document.

Comment: I thought I was in fact reloading only the needed content. how would I replace #main with #main from the loaded html? and how, on the opposite, would I reload the complete document? jQuery('html').html(html) does not work either.

Comment: maybe you could use jQuery.load instead? I think you can request a full page and add a selector for a particular element: `$('#main').load(url + ' #main', function() { /* something... */});`

Comment: @jpmorin you should post that answer; it is correct IMO.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you are reloading the entire page inside of the element that has an id of main.

```
jQuery('#main').html(html);
```

This is taking all of the reloaded html and stuffing it inside of the selected element.  Try to only reload the content inside of main instead of all of the content.

Answer (score 1):

As per the comments on the question:

Using the jQuery.load fonction, you can request a full page and add a selector for a particular element:

```
$('#main').load(url + ' #main', function() { /* something... */});
```

It will put the content received from the request automatically inside your `#main` element. See the docs for more details: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: This is great. Only disadvantage worth considering is wasted bandwidth and potential server processing. It would be more preferred to only request the content you need rather than getting all of it and filtering client side.

Answer (score 0):

#### How are these classes added?

The classes are added dynamically via the javascript you are using.

#### Happened to me too

I was using some javascripts too, which causes some classes to be inject in the DOM or to be precise in the `html` tag. That was because each time the javascript was loaded the js executed and added the classes depending on the screen, page, and some other factors.

#### JS in the layout file

You might have js attached inside the layout file. So each time an ajax request is sent to the page, the js file gets executed and adds the class once again. Because it is made to update the class depending on the output or input devices you are using; `class="no-touch"` This class is added because you donot have any touch input attached, if you had (touch screen LCD) then the class would have something else.

#### Usage of JS file and remedy of this

This totally depends on the way of usage of the JS.

I myself use js and they add the classes to my html tag, they need to add this to use it in future while you use their API. But at the same time each time I load the page, I remove the layout so that js don't get executed again.

And this will prevent this from happening again and again.

Comment: This answer is fundamentally incorrect. Whether or not those CSS classes are added by JS is completely irrelevant to the issue. The key problem here is that he is loading the entire document within a child element of the same document. This also means he's modernizr code could be being nested again and again, reexecuting. The problem is not really modernizr but rather that to refresh a portion of the page, he should not be loading/inserting the whole page again and should rather reload a small portion of content only.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is to remove the classes before you run the new html code.

```
function reloadSlides() {
jQuery.ajax({
    url: document.location.href,
    cache: true,
    success: function(html){
        jQuery("html").removeClass("js no-touch cssanimations csstransitions");
        jQuery('#main').html(html);
    }
});
```

But that doesn't really solve the problem. You have to find out, what part of your JS is adding those classes and place it into a static part of your html code. I would probably use Fileseek and search for the class names to find the JS.

Answer (score 0):

You have several feasible answers here, but none succinctly explain the root of the problem.

The problem here is that you are requesting the entire page and reinserting that entire page markup into a child element on the page for every reload.

You could filter the returned html content down using client side javascript, but it kind of ruins the efficiency benefits of AJAX in the first place. It would be more preferred to request only the content you need, therefore saving bandwidth and server processing overhead, etc.

This is often accomplished by adding a query string parameter to the current page request to tell the server you are making an ajax refresh request and so the response should not include all the out page markup/scripts/etc and just the primary content.

For example you could add a query string parameter like `&ajax=main` to the current page url which on the server side tells your code not to return a complete rendered page but rather just the content for the `main` page element. Of course you need to modify your server side page code to handle this.

This way you should not be re-executing your modernizr code on every refresh. This will save server resources and speed up the client experience in the browser too.

Here's a popular post about [manipulating the query string with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1090985/1002041). You could do it without jquery as a simple append, but the recommended jquery plugin in that post just handles a lot of edge cases for querystring handling.

Some simple tests you could do to verify:

- Watch the response to each of your refresh requests in firebug or chrome developer tools. Inspect the response to see if it is including the full page including header, scripts, etc..
- Count the number of refresh requests that have been made and note the correlation with the number of duplicate classes on your markup from modernizr.

The exact implementation for the server side partial view rendering will vary depending on your server technology stack (ie: different for different server backends - so do your own searching now that you know what to do)