# Find and replace between two points in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I am working on a web app at the moment, and I need to build a URL based on the users selections, the user can only select 1 item per product, so I should be able to create a url that looks like this,

> ?collection=French%20Curves&room=Bright%20And%20Airy&scene=best&wall_treatment=Wall Treatment 1

If for example the users selects a different `wall_treatment`, I need to some how search the string I'm generating, and replace that section with new relevant data?

I am googled and tried to use `.replace()` but that does not work, any ideas?

Comment: So why are you not just building up the string?

Comment: Sorry what do you mean, everytime something changes I append it to the string, but what if I want to change something that is already in the string?

Comment: Build the sting on demand...  `var url = baseURL + "collection=" + encodeURIComponent(xxx) + "&room=" + encodeURIComponent(yyy);`

Comment: seems like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090948/change-url-parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build a regexp matching any part of your string like this:

```
var urlPart = "wall_treatment";
var reg = new RegExp("([&?]+)" + urlPart + "=[^&]+");
```

Just replace `"wall_treatment"` with any variable holding a string / part of your URL. `[^&]+` matches anything up to the next occurence of `&` in the url.

Replace it like this:

```
var yourURL = "?collection=French%20Curves&room=Bright%20And%20Airy&scene=best&wall_treatment=Wall Treatment 1";
var new_value = "Wall Treatment 2";
yourURL.replace(reg, "$1" + urlPart + "=" + new_value);
```

Having solved that, let me advise that you should probably try to build your url from an object or an array rather than replacing variables in the url string:

```
var myURLSearchObject = {},
    addURLSearchPart = function(key, value) {
      myURLSearchObject[key] = value;
    },
    buildURLSearch = function() {
      var string = "?";
      for (var key in myURLSearchObject) {
        if (myURLSearchObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
           string.length > 1 && (string += '&');
           string += key;
           string += '=';
           string += myURLSearchObject[key];
        }
      }
      return string;
    };
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
addURLSearchPart('hello', 'hi');
addURLSearchPart('bye', 'goodbye');

buildURLSearch();
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
     var String ='?collection=French%20Curves&room=Bright%20And%20Airy&scene=best&wall_treatment=Wall Treatment 1';
     var Urls = String.split('wall_treatment=');         
     String  =  String.replace(Urls[1], "YourString");
     console.log(String); //output : ?collection=French%20Curves&room=Bright%20And%20Airy&scene=best&wall_treatment=YourString
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace like this:

```
wt="something"; // user entered value

s = '?collection=French%20Curves&room=Bright%20And%20Airy&scene=best&wall_treatment=Wall Treatment 1';
s = s.replace(/([?&]wall_treatment=)[^&]*/i, "$1" + wt);
//=> ?collection=French%20Curves&room=Bright%20And%20Airy&scene=best&wall_treatment=something
```

Answer (score 0):

You could build each time the url new instead of replacing something in a string:

```
var collection = 'French Curves';
var room = 'Bright and Airy';
var scene = 'best';
var wallTreatment = 'Wall Treatment 1';

newUrl = '?collection=' + collection + '&room=' + room + '&scene=' + scene + '&wall_treatment=' + wallTreatment';
```

Then a bit urlencode and everything should be fine. You could do this in a foreach too, if your `GET`-Parameters are dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
(?i)(?<=wall_treatment=)[^&]+
```

Build the above regex up where wall_treatment can be any parameter from your url.
If it was `scene` the regex will capture `best` if `wall_treatment` the regex will capture `Wall Treatment 1`.

I hope this helps!