# jQuery - How to replace just a specific part from a link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have many links like the following code:

```
<a class="changelink" href="SignForEvent.php?id=1&page=1>Click Here</a>
<a class="changelink" href="SignForEvent.php?id=2&page=1>Click Here</a>
<a class="changelink" href="SignForEvent.php?id=3&page=1>Click Here</a>
<a class="changelink" href="SignForEvent.php?id=4&page=2>Click Here</a>
<a class="changelink" href="SignForEvent.php?id=5&page=2>Click Here</a>
<a class="changelink" href="SignForEvent.php?id=6&page=2>Click Here</a>
```

How with jQuery i can change only the `&page=` argument to be for instance '10'.

In other version of my question how can i save all the structure of the link before `page=` and change only this argument?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/179717/5139222)  before asking a queston?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [add or update query string parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999118/add-or-update-query-string-parameter)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090948/change-url-parameters

Comment: @TonyStark Please mark best answer to ending this discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `replace` method to change target character to another

```js
$("a.changelink").each(function(){
    var href = $(this).attr("href").replace(/&page=[\d]+/, "&page=10");
    $(this).attr("href", href);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="changelink" href="SignForEvent.php?id=1&page=1">Click Here</a>
<a class="changelink" href="SignForEvent.php?id=2&page=1">Click Here</a>
<a class="changelink" href="SignForEvent.php?id=3&page=1">Click Here</a>
<a class="changelink" href="SignForEvent.php?id=4&page=2">Click Here</a>
<a class="changelink" href="SignForEvent.php?id=5&page=2">Click Here</a>
<a class="changelink" href="SignForEvent.php?id=6&page=2">Click Here</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `$().each` to iterate the elements and use `.replace()` with regex:

```js
var newPage = 10;
$(function(){
  $(".changelink").each(function(){
    var link = $(this).attr("href");
    var currentPage = link.match(/page=([\d]+)/)[1];
    $(this).attr("href", link.replace("page=" + currentPage, "page=" + newPage))
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="changelink" href="SignForEvent.php?id=1&page=2">Click Here</a>
<a class="changelink" href="SignForEvent.php?id=2&page=2">Click Here</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('changelink').attr("href",lnk.replace('SignForEvent','textThatWillReplaceSignForEvent'));
```