# Change part of a URL with JQUERY

Tags: jquery

I need to update a URL parameter on a drop down change event with jquery. I got this code that works well when I got a single parameter in the URL, but when I got many parameters, the country in this case, will be deleted.

Here the code:

```
$('#state-input').change(function () {

      var hrefElement = $("#municipality-input");
      var href = hrefElement.data('autocomplete-url');

      href = href.replace(/(stateId=)[A-Z].+/ig, '$1' + $(this).val());
      hrefElement.attr('data-autocomplete-url', href);
});
```

The URL on page load:

> data-autocomplete-url="/SKU/GetCities?stateId=QC&countryId=CA"

On the change event

> data-autocomplete-url="/SKU/GetCities?stateId=NB"

What I want :

> data-autocomplete-url="/SKU/GetCities?stateId=NB&countryId=CA"

Is there any way to keep the country with a little changes of the code I got?

Thanks

Comment: Check the plugin suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1090966/259881

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget the second part when replacing the regex.
Maybe you need to do this:

```
href = href.replace(/(stateId=)[A-Z]+(.*)/ig, '$1' + $(this).val() + '$2');
```

So the result will be:

```
$('#state-input').change(function () {

      var hrefElement = $("#municipality-input");
      var href = hrefElement.data('autocomplete-url');

      href = href.replace(/(stateId=)[A-Z]+(.*)/ig, '$1' + $(this).val() + '$2');
      hrefElement.attr('data-autocomplete-url', href);
});
```