# Replace URLs with historypush

Tags: javascript, browser-history

I use this code for handling content fadeIns from http://stackoverflow.com/a/10997390/11236

```
function updateURLParameter(url, param, paramVal){
    var newAdditionalURL = "";
    var tempArray = url.split("?");
    var baseURL = tempArray[0];
    var additionalURL = tempArray[1];
    var temp = "";
    if (additionalURL) {
        tempArray = additionalURL.split("&");
        for (var i=0; i<tempArray.length; i++){
            if(tempArray[i].split('=')[0] != param){
                newAdditionalURL += temp + tempArray[i];
                temp = "&";
            }
        }
    }

    var rows_txt = temp + "" + param + "=" + paramVal;
    return baseURL + "?" + newAdditionalURL + rows_txt;
}

var newURL = updateURLParameter(window.location.href, 'locId', 'newLoc');
newURL = updateURLParameter(newURL, 'resId', 'newResId');
```

I update the URL with:

```
window.history.replaceState('', '', updateURLParameter(window.location.href, "param", "value"));
```

It changes to URL how I want to - but it is not saved in the url history. So if I change the URL with this and click the back button, the url is not changing to the last state.

But I thought this is what history.pushState is doing? What do I have to change to save the URLs in the history? So when the user is clicking the back button, the content changes depending on the url (like a normal url path).

Comment: use pushState instead of replaceState. I know you talked about pushState but you are not actually using it in the code you showed

Comment: ok, you are right.. ;) But the problem is still, that the content is not reloading everytime I click the back button. So parameter changes, but the content not.

Comment: just read this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API and use popstate event