# Use value from data attribute as url parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, url-parameters

As base I use: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10997390/11236

On click, I want to take the data attribute value of the clicked element and use it as url parameter. I don't want to destroy the actual behavior, I just want to extend it. I am trying a few hours now, but without a result.

HTML

```
<div class="button one">Click me</div>
<div class="button two" data-url="this-should-be-the-parameter">Click me</div>
```

JS URL Controler

```
  function updateURLParameter(url, param, paramVal){
      var newAdditionalURL = "";
      var tempArray = url.split("?");
      var baseURL = tempArray[0];
      var additionalURL = tempArray[1];
      var temp = "";
      if (additionalURL) {
          tempArray = additionalURL.split("&");
          for (var i=0; i<tempArray.length; i++){
              if(tempArray[i].split('=')[0] != param){
                  newAdditionalURL += temp + tempArray[i];
                  temp = "&";
              }
          }
      }

      var rows_txt = temp + "" + param + "=" + paramVal;
      return baseURL + "?" + newAdditionalURL + rows_txt;
  }

    var newURL = updateURLParameter(window.location.href, 'locId', 'newLoc');
    newURL = updateURLParameter(newURL, 'resId', 'newResId');
```

JS Click Handler

```
$( ".button" ).click(function() {
  window.history.replaceState('', '', updateURLParameter(window.location.href, "specificurl", "customvalue"));
});
```

So, I have to check, if the clicked div contains the attribute "data-url", and if yes, this should be used as parameter for "customvalue"

As result, Url should look like:

```
Click on ".buton.one": xyz.com/?specificurl=customvalue
Click on ".buton.two": xyz.com/?specificurl=this-should-be-the-parameter
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In modern browsers there is a much simpler built in [URL API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) you can now use.

In button click handler check if the data attribute is set and has a value using `data()`. If it is ... use `URL.searchParams.set(key, value)`

```js
$('.button').click(function(){
   var url = new URL(location.href),
      dataUrl = $(this).data('url');
   if(dataUrl){
    url.searchParams.set('someVar', dataUrl ); 
   }
    
   console.log(url.href)

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button one">Click me</div>
<div class="button two" data-url="this-should-be-the-parameter">Click me</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get/set attribute value in `Jquery` by `$(element).attr()`. Find the value and use where you want.

```js
console.log($("#input").attr('data-attr'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="input" data-attr="my_value" type="text" />
```