# how to add param with javascript

Tags: javascript, laravel

```
<script>
        
   document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      window.location.search += '?param=42';
            
   }, false);
</script>
```

my page keep reload when I put this code

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow, please edit your question, learn [ask].

Comment: Yes because you added it on domcontent loaded. changing the search property of window.location will cause it to reload

Comment: might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090948/change-url-parameters/65701780#65701780

Comment: I'm pretty sure setting values of `window.location` will cause the page to reload. You'll need an if-statement to prevent this

Comment: What do you expect to happen?

Comment: i just want to add dynamic param..