# jQuery query string traversal

Tags: javascript, jquery, query-string

> **Possible Duplicates:**
> [JavaScript query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647259/javascript-query-string)
> [get querystring with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-querystring-with-jquery)

Is there an object/method in JavaScript to turn a string like this: `param1=2&param2=1&param3=5` into some sort of dictionary, so that I can refer to each element as `mystring['param1']` or `mystring[0]`?

Can jQuery help here?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-querystring-with-jquery

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/647259/javascript-query-string

Comment: Oh, and: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150404/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-read-manipulate-query-string-params-using-javascript

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/647259/javascript-query-string

Comment: interesting that the question is duplicate but the solutions are different. so equal question but not identical content == != ===

Answer (score 8, accepted):

this is my try.

```
var a = 'param1=2&param2=1&param3=5';
var b = a.split('&');
var final ={};
$.each(b, function(x,y){
    var temp = y.split('=');
    final[temp[0]] = temp[1];
});
console.log( final);
```

This returns an object like the dictionary that you needed:

```
{
    param1 : "2",
    param2 : "1",
    param3 : "5",
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a plugin for this. http://plugins.jquery.com/project/query-object - You can play with an online demo of it at : http://test.blairmitchelmore.com/jquery.query/?name=jonathan&age=26

There's also [jqUrl](http://www.oakcitygraphics.com/jquery/jqURL/jqURLdemo.html?var1=1&var2=2&var3=3), which allows you to call items form the query string like this:

```
$.jqURL.get('var2');
```

Comment: While this is what I need, I think plugin is an overkill for such a simple problem.

Comment: That would depend on the size of the plugin. These aren't large.