# How to pass a parameter to a javascript through a url and display it on a page?

Tags: javascript, parameters

For instance, I have a url like this : www.mysite.com/my_app.html

How do I pass a value " Use_Id = abc " to it and use javascript to display on that page ?

Comment: So, do you want to display all the parameters from a URL (if I'm not mistaken)?

Comment: If so, see my answer it returns an array. From there you can pick and choose which you want.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Shouldn't be too difficult to write your own without the need for an external library.

```
// www.mysite.com/my_app.html?Use_Id=abc 

var GET = {};
var query = window.location.search.substring(1).split("&");
for (var i = 0, max = query.length; i < max; i++)
{
    if (query[i] === "") // check for trailing & with no param
        continue;

    var param = query[i].split("=");
    GET[decodeURIComponent(param[0])] = decodeURIComponent(param[1] || "");
}
```

Usage: `GET.Use_id` or `GET["Use_id"]`.  You can also check if a parameter is present even if it has a null value using `"Use_id" in GET` (will return true or false).

Comment: Can you explain the last line? 
    GET[decodeURIComponent(param[0])] = decodeURIComponent(param[1] || "");

Comment: nevermind, I got it: decodes html-encoded string (%20 etc) back to normal.

Answer (score 6):

Call the page `www.mysite.com/my_app.html?Use_Id=abc`

Then in that page use a javascript function like:

```
var urlParam = function(name, w){
    w = w || window;
    var rx = new RegExp('[\&|\?]'+name+'=([^\&\#]+)'),
        val = w.location.search.match(rx);
    return !val ? '':val[1];
}
```

To use it:

```
var useId = urlParam('Use_Id');
```

The second parameter `w` is optional, but useful if you want to read parameters on iframes or parent windows.

Comment: Your code is pretty useful! Thank, you. What about post method like in php?

Comment: @S.P.H.I.N.X when you make a post to a PHP page, there is no client javascript anymore. 
You need to do a parsing with PHP on the server either data posted or in the url like here.

Answer (score 2):

`www.mysite.com/my_app.html?use_id=abs`

```
var qs = new QueryString()

// use_id is now available in the use_id variable
var use_id = qs.get("use_id");
```

Comment: QueryString Code can be found at https://web.archive.org/web/20101025074108/http://adamv.com/dev/javascript/files/querystring.js

Answer (score 1):

```
www.mysite.com/my_app.html?Use_Id=abc


var querystring = window.location.querystring;
var myValue = querystring["Use_Id"];
```

http://prettycode.org/2009/04/21/javascript-query-string/

Answer (score 0):

There's a similar question on this here [What is the easiest way to read/manipulate query string params using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150404/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-read-manipulate-query-string-params-using-javascript)

Which seems to recommend using jQuery's Querystring plugin: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/query-object

Answer (score 0):

Your server side script could read the value and set it in a hidden form field which your JS could then read.