# Adding parameters to url

Tags: javascript

I try to test the function s.Util.getQueryParam.

The url I have is in format

```
http://project1/project1.html
```

I would like to add some parameters in the url after that in order to have something like this format

```
http://project1/project1.html/?id=03
```

I try to use this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2405540)

```
// www.mysite.com/my_app.html?Use_Id=abc 

var GET = {};
var query = window.location.search.substring(1).split("&");
for (var i = 0, max = query.length; i < max; i++)
{
    if (query[i] === "") // check for trailing & with no param
        continue;

    var param = query[i].split("=");
    GET[decodeURIComponent(param[0])] = decodeURIComponent(param[1] || "");
}
```

I try to add in Get this id=03 but it is not working when I refresh my browser I can't see the parameter. Is it possible to help me how can I run it with the right way?

Comment: That snippet of code is for extracting parameters from the URL, not adding them to the URL. Are you trying to add parameters to the URL, inside the web browser? If so, why?

Comment: @harmic Yes I try to add parameter to url in order to test locally some analytics urls. Also I show this example (http://stackoverflow.com/a/487049/5018097) but I am not pretty sure for key and value. Any help if it possible please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add / Change parameter of URL and redirect to the new URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13063838/add-change-parameter-of-url-and-redirect-to-the-new-url)

Comment: @Mike thank you but what should I use in order to test the answer with the paramName and paramValue

Answer (score 3):

You can modify `window.location.search` to add query parameters. This will cause the browser to load the new URL (the page will be refreshed).

Example: `window.location.search = '?id=03'`.

Comment: Thank you it was worked for me but with an unexpected way. I can see the parameters in url but it always shows that it is loading and I can't see the content of the page