# Issue with Decoding %20 from URL

Tags: javascript, url, decoding

I have found that the following thread provides an extremely useful way to create permalinks or to pass string values via a URL:

[Original Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405355/how-to-pass-a-parameter-to-a-javascript-through-a-url-and-display-it-on-a-page)

Unfortunately, if you wanted to pass the string "test string", for example, to a specific `<div>` via the URL and display it as simple text, the above thread doesn't seem to decode white space if your URL looks like this:

```
http://www.abc123.org/subpage.html?test%20string
```

The code will simply take anything in the URL passed the "?" and it will appear as "simple%20text".

Is there a simple way to do something similar to the [Thread's accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2405540/7932241) so that all %20 can be replaced with white space? Thanks!

Comment: `unescape` or `decodeURIComponent`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`decodeURI()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI):

> Replaces each escape sequence in the encoded URI with the character
>   that it represents, but does not decode escape sequences that could
>   not have been introduced by encodeURI. The character “#” is not
>   decoded from escape sequences.

```js
const result = decodeURI('http://www.abc123.org/subpage.html?test%20string');

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I got decodeURI() to work in my environment. All the best!