# How to create dynamic link with static hosting?

Tags: javascript, forms, frontend, backend, client-side

I have a function in JavaScript which returns square of the given number. To get output I take input from user in a form field and on clicking a button trigger that function.

I want to remove that typing parameter and button clicking thing. Is there a way I can have a link which on clicked will give me square of say 100. I want to have that link dynamic. Example, square.com/100 should give me square of 100. Square.com/2 should give square of 2. But this is to be done on dynamic hosting like GitHub pages.

frameworks: I am not using any framework but I will host it on github pages so any framework that will work with github pages that is static hosting is also good

As we are not using any backend processing I think this can be done. But not sure how

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking. Please see [ask].

Comment: @isherwood thanks for suggestion. Please relook the modified question.

Comment: It's still a very broad question. Sure, that's done all the time. What have you tried and what's not working?

Comment: You can take a look at query parameters (in particular the [get method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/get)), and see if that's a solution for you

Comment: @A_A can you add that as an answer? I will mark it as accepted

Comment: That question's been asked an answered many times. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405355/how-to-pass-a-parameter-to-a-javascript-through-a-url-and-display-it-on-a-page

Comment: Missed that. Thanks for the reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use query parameters in a url (e.g. https://example.org/?number=1234) and then parse it client side. One way to do that is:

```js
const params = new URLSearchParams(document.location.search);
const myNumber = Number(params.get('number'))
```

For more ways to parse the query string see [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)