# changing href doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

i like to **add query string dynamically** in in url. the whole table is from
**jquery Datatable**

when i change select box(on change) ,
i need to add **this** value to all anchors in td.so i did that, through following code.
when i alert **href** i getting what i want

> ("XXX?YY=YY&bsort=ZZ")

.
 but the anchor href's doesn't have that (&bsort=XX) query string(checking by fire bug)
whats wrong ?

mycode

```
$('select[name="category_table_length"]').change(function(){
    var b,href;
    b = $(this).val();
        $('td a').each(function(){
        href = $(this).attr('href');
        href = href+"&bsort="+b; 

        $(this).attr('href',href);
        });
});
```

Comment: yes it does !. i can get alert  inside each

Comment: Can you test the href content with `console.log` just before re-assigning it ? (And bring us the result)

Comment: sorry i'm only getting this(console is not defined) error

Comment: Ok, use `alert("Href = " + href);` instead.

Comment: before assigning :Href =category?id=1&sort=next ...after Href = category?id=1&sort=next&bsort=50

Comment: the table from jquery data table is that affect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/7QTzt/

Is your HTML valid?

BTW, your code doesn't take into account having to remove a "&bsort" property when you select from the dropdown a second time. Perhaps consider [a more sophisticated approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150404/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-read-manipulate-query-string-params-using-javascript).

Comment: yeah i'm also getting result from alone page. in my case the table from jquery data table is that affect

Comment: @gowri: Then the testcase in your question is invalid and you need to provide the actual code that fails.

Answer (score 0):

try this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/adescalzo/5F6n2/):

HTML:

```
<select name="category_table_length">
    <option value="1">sort 1</option>
    <option value="2">sort 2</option>
    <option value="3">sort 3</option>    
</select>

<table id="mytable">
    <tr>
        <td><a href="/page.php?data=a">anchor 1</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="/page.php?data=a">anchor 2</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$('select[name="category_table_length"]').change(function(event){

    var 
        actual_value = $(this).val(),
        new_href = "";

    $('#mytable tr td a').each(function(i, el){

        if (!$(el).attr("original_href"))
            $(el).attr("original_href", $(el).attr('href') )

        new_href = $(el).attr("original_href") + "&bsort=" + actual_value;

        $(el)
            .attr('href', new_href)
            .html("change " + new_href);

    });
});
```

if you do not have "?" should change to:

```
new_href = $(el).attr("original_href") + "?bsort=" + actual_value;
```

Comment: yeah i'm also getting result from alone page. in my case the table from jquery data table is that affect .. any idea !

Comment: what is the use of   .html("change " + new_href);

Comment: you could put the html table. the `. html(` I got to see what worked well, because the links are fake